# java JTable cell change

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a java JTable, when users click a cell, it will change to a dropdown or textField, users can make change. Then users can click a save button, that cell will go back a label.

How to implement this ? a simple example will be better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point for such questions is Sun/ Oracle's tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Have a look at cell renderers, cell editors, table models and events.

Comment: @user534009, check out this link by Puce, pay close attention to the cell editors, that is really what you are after.  There are examples in the tutorial if you need them.